# How would I type an object that contains a class/constructor?

Tags: typescript, class

Having Trouble using Typescript class decorators, but for simplicity my example wont include them

```
class AClass {
    handle() {
       console.log("Handled")
    }
}

function callHandler(constructor: Type) {
   return new constructor().handle()
}

callHandler(AClass)
```

I've tried replacing `Type` with `Function` but I get:

```
file:ln:rw - error TS2351: This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'Function' has no construct signatures.

ln             new constructor().handle()
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Besides `any`, Is there any type i can use that is considered constructable?

Answer (score 0):

I Found: [Typescript issue 17572](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17572#issuecomment-319994873)
while writing this question and was able to find the type

```
abstract class EmptyAbstractClass {}
type Class<T = {}> = typeof EmptyAbstractClass & {prototype: T};
```

and `Class<{ handle: () => void }>` worked for my code.